# Deploy OpenLdap using docker

Tags: linux, docker, ldap, openldap, system-administration

How can I deploy openldap server using docker I tryed this command but the image doesn't exist

docker run --name isva-openldap --detach ibmcom/verify-access-openldap:latest

Answer (score 1):

Search dockerhub for openldap. I see a few, like bitnami/openldap. I've been using osixia/openldap with some success. That one seems to come up in most searches when I need help too.

The ibmcom/verify-access-openldap one seems to be an extension of the osixia one.